# Does having a lot of unused classes/rules have any performance impact on a web page?

Tags: html, css

Will having a large number of unused stylesheet rules/classes have a significant effect on the performance - load time, rendering time?

Comment: Definitely. Also, it would become such a pain eventually to maintain any application of that sort of junk code contained in it.

Answer (score 3):

Well, since the browser has to download and parse the entire file, it'll have an impact. How big of an impact it is depends on how big the file is, how fast is the computer said browser is running on, and how fast is the user's internet connection.

I've just tried a .css file of 10 000 rows full of redundant information, spreading the relevant styles all over it. None of my browsers actually seemed to give a damn, and I didn't notice any visible slowdown (bear in mind the file's on localhost). It still doesn't make it a particulary good idea tho.

Answer (score 1):

If you care about performance you should remove those styles. As others said, the browser still needs to download the file. That's the first problem. After that you have parsing which may also be improved. I'll suggest to use tools like [CSSLint](http://csslint.net/) or [PageSpeed](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/?hl=bg). And yes, the browsers nowadays are doing great job. It's incredibly fast, but even there is an operation which takes few microseconds it will be better to save this time. Also, you will work better and faster with less code.